# Wrong Mac OS X framework gets loaded

Tags: python, macos, qt4, macports, vtk

I've compiled a Python module using my own Qt4 library located in `~/opt/qt-4.6.0/`,
but when I try to import that module, the dynamic libraries that get loaded are from my MacPorts Qt4 installation.

```
$ /opt/local/bin/python2.6
>>> import vtk
objc[58041]: Class QMacSoundDelegate is implemented in both /Users/luis/opt/qt-4.6.0/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui and /opt/local/libexec/qt4-mac/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui. Using implementation from /opt/local/libexec/qt4-mac/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui.
objc[58045]: Class QCocoaColorPanelDelegate is implemented in both /Users/luis/opt/qt-4.6.0/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui and /opt/local/libexec/qt4-mac/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui. Using implementation from /opt/local/libexec/qt4-mac/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui.
[... more output like above ...]
>>>
```

Is there a way of telling Python (also installed from MacPorts) to load the frameworks located in my `~/opt/qt-4.6.0/lib/` directory? I'm not sure what environment variables to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to put your libraries in `~/opt/qt/...` before the MacPorts' libraries before invoking python (take a look at `~/.profile` for an example of how to do this if you don't know; MacPorts does the exact same thing to put its libraries on the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`). `dyld`, the OS X dynamic linker uses `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to find libraries at load time (among other methods); See `man dyld` for more info.

Comment: I had tried LD_LIBRARY_PATH before, but it didn't work. Thanks a lot for the pointer to `dyld`, though. Its man page is very informative. Let's see if I can use that to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you try DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH as well?

Comment: ...just saw your answer. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: I just tried again with only DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, but it wasn't sufficient. Frameworks must get loaded different than the usual .dylib's, hence the need for DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after Barry Wark pointed me to `dyld(1)`, the man page described a number of variables that I could set.

The first hint came from setting the environment variable `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES`, so I could see what libraries were being loaded.

```
$ DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 python -c 'import vtk'
[... snip ...]
dyld: loaded: /opt/local/libexec/qt4-mac/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
dyld: loaded: /opt/local/lib/libpng12.0.dylib
dyld: loaded: /opt/local/libexec/qt4-mac/lib/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/QtSql
dyld: loaded: /opt/local/libexec/qt4-mac/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
[... snip ...]
dyld: loaded: /Users/luis/opt/qt-4.6.0/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
dyld: loaded: /Users/luis/opt/qt-4.6.0/lib/QtSql.framework/Versions/4/QtSql
dyld: loaded: /Users/luis/opt/qt-4.6.0/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
[... snip ...]
$
```

Ah, so the frameworks for qt4-mac were indeed being loaded first, just as we suspected. Rereading the man page, the next thing we can try is changing the `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` so that it knows where to look. I now added this line to the end of my `~/.bash_profile`

```
export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="${HOME}/opt/qt-4.6.0/lib:${DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH}"
```

and after logging back in, we try importing the vtk python module again:

```
$ python -c 'import vtk'
$
```

There's no output this time. Issue fixed!